# Dynamically reincarnating a Type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to deserialize a stream of data, consists (conceptually) of the pair `("TypeName", "blah"`, where `"blah"` is appropriate input to `read` for some object of type `TypeName`.

Is there a way to dynamically choose `read`'s result type? Would I use something like `Data.Dynamic` or `Data.Typable`?

Comment: Only if you have some kind of registry for all the types you need.

Comment: Registry? I have a closed set of types, but I'm not sure how to use that. Hmm. I'm looking into making a `Read` instance for `Data.Typable.TypeRep`.

Comment: With a closed set of types you can use a case statement on the type name, each arm using read and toDyn with a type signature.

Comment: augustss has the idea, I think. Creating a `Read` instance for `TypeRep` will not get you very far; it would allow you to use `read` to parse your type names, but you would still need a `case` switch to feed that type to `read` when called on the value.

Comment: @isturdy No, that's true. I realized that when I couldn't find a suitable function in `Data.Typable` that had `TypeRep` on the left of a function arrow. I thought you could convert it back to a true type (rather than a data-level encoding of a type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Dynamic
import Control.Applicative

readMay :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
readMay s = case reads s of
    (a,[]):_ -> Just a
    _ -> Nothing

reconstruct :: Typeable a => (Maybe a -> r) -> (String, String) -> r
reconstruct k (typ,val) =
    case typ of
      "string" -> k $ cast =<< (readMay val :: Maybe String)
      "int"    -> k $ cast =<< (readMay val :: Maybe Int)
      "double" -> k $ cast =<< (readMay val :: Maybe Double)

reconstructToDyn (typ,val) =
    case typ of
      "string" -> toDyn <$> (readMay val :: Maybe String)
      "int"    -> toDyn <$> (readMay val :: Maybe Int)
      "double" -> toDyn <$> (readMay val :: Maybe Double)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to complicate this by adding a lot of Template Haskell, but I've come to (almost) the same conclusion.